# Shortening a long string

Tags: javascript, html, string, object

This line of code is longer than 80 characters - is there any way I can make it shorter?

```
const playerVars = Object.assign({}, oldSettings.playerVars, newSettings.playerVars);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnj7quby/10/) is the entire project on a JSFiddle.

This is the function in which the line is contained:

```
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, oldSettings.playerVars, newSettings.playerVars);
    const settings = Object.assign({}, oldSettings, newSettings);
    settings.playerVars = playerVars;
    return settings;
}
```

Comment: Make your variable names shorter?

Comment: Do you know what would work here in making the line shorter?

Comment: Split the statement into multiple lines?

Comment: @Bergi Can you provide your answer on here so I can see it?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your parameter names to be shorter:

```
function combineSettings(oldS, newS) {
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, oldS.playerVars, newS.playerVars);
    const settings = Object.assign({}, oldS, newS);
    settings.playerVars = playerVars;
    return settings;
}
```

Comment: By changing parameter names to be shorter we are loosing their self-documentation. `oldSettings`, `newSettings` are self-explaining.  Isn't it to make code readable and extendable by splitting long line to many lines? What if 3,4,5-th variable will appear in assign chain?

Answer (score 1):

You can also make an `"alias"` function for the whole `Object.assign({}, ...args)` and move the params to separate lines like this:

```js
const merge = (...args) => Object.assign({}, ...args)

function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
  const playerVars = merge(
     oldSettings.playerVars, 
     newSettings.playerVars
  );
  const settings = merge(oldSettings, newSettings);
  settings.playerVars = playerVars;
  return settings;
}
```

This is more trivial/simple, **readable** and also adds `merge` as another function you can later use etc.

FYI if you are using `lodash` [merge function already exists](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) as well as [`_.defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#defaults) and [`_.extend/assignIn`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assignIn). **Note**: obviously not suggesting you use lodash just for this :)

Comment: IMHO `Object.assign({}, ` vs `merge(`  - not a big deal. main problem how many variables in future can be added to it's arguments. So better to split it to lines.

Comment: Now this line is longer than 80 characters: const playerVars = merge(oldSettings.playerVars, newSettings.playerVars);

Comment: @JDawg simply move the params into separate lines. Updated the answer.

Comment: btw, I'm trying to avoid lodash, since new ES standards does most of lodash's work.

Comment: @num8er sure. I still think it adds tons of value. Especially its functional `lodash/fp` part. Also regardless of how good ES6 is it still does not have all the helper functions lodash has and you would have to write them yourself if you wanted them so there is still a lot of value there.

Comment: @Akrion yes, it's better to write own utils when it's needed. For example I extend it like this in project's shared repository: http://joxi.ru/52aJJbh46DJjA0  so I keep idea of minimum dependencies, maximum effective code - it makes develop myself and keep an eye on ES new features.

Comment: Why write your own where there is a library which has been battle tested by a horde of developers and has proven solid browser support etc etc. I understand if you need a simple `sortBy` or something else trivial but the moment you end up adding those up you are better off using something already proven and tree shake it to only get the elements you need. Like are you going to write your own date functions too? Or just tree shake/pick what you need from moment/date-fns? etc

Comment: `Or just tree shake/pick what you need from moment/date-fns?` - exactly. I try not load functions that will not consume + I'm making app start faster by reading small amount of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not what StackOverflow is for you can refactor a bit more :

```
function combine( ...args ) {
    return Object.assign( {}, ...args );
}

function combineSettings( oldSettings, newSettings ) {
    return combine( oldSettings, newSettings, {
        playerVars : combine( oldSettings.playerVars, newSettings.playerVars )
    } );
}

console.log( combineSettings(
    { a : "foo", playerVars : { b : "bar" } },
    { b : "bar", playerVars : { a : "foo" } }
) ); // { a: 'foo', playerVars: { b: 'bar', a: 'foo' }, b: 'bar' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a few variables? Like this

```
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
    const oldSet1 = oldSettings.playerVars;
    const newSet1 = newSettings.playerVars;

    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, oldSet1, newSet1);
    const settings = Object.assign({}, oldSettings, newSettings);
    settings.playerVars = playerVars;
    return settings;
```

}

Comment: Creating new variables is not good practice. Yes it's also solution, but in some companies such code can be reason that changes people's opinion for Your candidacy. Bergi already gave solution in comments to question: `Split the statement into multiple lines`

Answer (score -1):

I like to code as if I write in functional programming language.

So my solution for Your question will be:

```js
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
  return Object.assign(
    {}, 
    oldSettings, 
    newSettings,
    {
      playerVars: 
        Object.assign(
          {}, 
          oldSettings.playerVars, 
          newSettings.playerVars
        )
    }
  );
}

const settings1 = {
  someSet1: 'a',
  playerVars: {
    notifications: true,
    someVar: 1
  }
};

const settings2 = {
  someSet1: 'aa',
  someSet2: 'b',
  playerVars: {
    notifications: false, 
    mail: "somebody@gmail.com"
  }
};


console.log(combineSettings(settings1, settings2));
```

If You want to minify one-liner You've to move that variables to array and then just call `Object.assign` with spread operator:

```js
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
  var playerVars = [
    oldSettings.playerVars, 
    newSettings.playerVars
  ];
  playerVars = Object.assign({}, ...playerVars); // Your one-liner
  // other operations
  return {playerVars};
}

const settings1 = {
  playerVars: {
    notifications: true,
    someVar: 1
  }
};

const settings2 = {
  playerVars: {
    notifications: false, 
    mail: "somebody@gmail.com"
  }
};


console.log(combineSettings(settings1, settings2));
```

OR

Split it to lines:

```js
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
  var playerVars = 
    Object.assign(
      {}, 
      oldSettings.playerVars, 
      newSettings.playerVars
    );
  // other operations
  return {playerVars};
}

const settings1 = {
  playerVars: {
    notifications: true,
    someVar: 1
  }
};

const settings2 = {
  playerVars: {
    notifications: false, 
    mail: "somebody@gmail.com"
  }
};


console.log(combineSettings(settings1, settings2));
```

**Warning:** By changing parameter names to be shorter we are loosing their self-documentation. `oldSettings`, `newSettings` are self-explaining.

So only beautiful way to make code readable and extendable by splitting long line to many lines.

I've googled it by query: `js style guide` and found these good resources to read:

https://standardjs.com/

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html

https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide

**Extra:** most of IDEs has beautify method that will do it for You

Comment: I don't know what to google. *Which* js style guide do I need, and *what particular* best practice would it recommend?